# Merge multiple RAR parts (file.part01.rar, file.part02.rar, etc.) to file.rar

Tags: command-line, archive, rar

If one has multi-part zip files (`a.z01`, `a.z02`, `a.zip`), one can merge the split files into the original zip file by running

`zip -F a.zip --out output.zip`

But I couldn't find an equivalent for split rar files (`a.part01.rar`, `a.part02.rar`). The standard `rar` tool has no such option. Any other tool/method?

**I'm not looking to extract the files,** I know I can simply run `rar` on the partial files. I need to re-merge the split rar files into one big/united rar file.
(I would also prefer not to extract and then use `rar` to create the merged file).

Comment: I don't think there is a way, you have to extract and compress again.